# Get child element from element through an event with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Goal**

What I'm trying to achieve is that whenever the user clicks on the `.menu-item` element, the dropdown element `.menu-item-dropdown` will get a class that will show the element.

**Problem**

Currently, when I click on the `.menu-item` class element, the returned value from the `console.log` in `showMobileNavDropdown()` returns `null`. When clicking, the `event.target` element is `.menu-item-main` and not `.menu-item`. **This happens only when I click on the text of the `li`.** Otherwise this works as intended.

What would be the best way to include the `li` text so that I can still grab the `.menu-item-dropdown` class?

**Vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="nav">
            <div class="nav-left">
                <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav-center">
                <ul class="menu-items">
                    <li
                        class="menu-item"
                        @click="showMobileNavDropdown($event)"
                    >
                        <!-- Main Title On Nav -->
                        <a class="menu-item-main" href="#">Company</a>

                        <!-- Dropdown -->
                        <div class="menu-item-dropdown">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-right">
                <a href="" class="btn">Contact us</a>
            </div>

            <div class="hamburger" @click="openMobileNav">
                <span class="ham-line"></span>
                <span class="ham-line ham-line-2"></span>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="mobile-nav"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        openMobileNav() {
            var mobileNav = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav");
            mobileNav.classList.toggle("showMobileNav");
        },

        // This function
        showMobileNavDropdown(event) {
            console.log(event); // This element returns 'menu-item-main' and not 'menu-item'
            console.log(event.target.querySelector(".menu-item-dropdown"));
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: If the click-target is reliably the element with the class `menu-item-main` you could try to query `event.target.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".menu-item-dropdown")` in `showMobileNavDropdown`. Here're the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling).

Comment: Hi @AndreNuechter, thank you for your answer. I've updated the question after trying a few things. At the moment the main issue is that the text, so the `menu-item-main` differs when I click on the rest of the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a longer list of possible click-targets and can't or won't just use [refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html), I would use event-delegation and in the click-handler check, whether the clicked element is inside a clickable parent and based on that, toggle a class on the parent, which can then be used to select the child in CSS, for example to change it's opacity.

```js
Vue.component('foo-bar', {      
  methods: {
    toggleSubItemVisibility({ target }) {
      const item = target.closest('.nav-item');
      // we check because the user might have clicked on the surrounding ul
      if (item) {
        item.classList.toggle('active');
      }
    }
  },
  template: `
  <nav>
    <ul @click="toggleSubItemVisibility">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="nav-label">Foo</span>
        <div class="nav-sub-item">More details...</div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="nav-label">Bar</span>
        <div class="nav-sub-item">More details...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
nav ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 12px;
}

.nav-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-sub-item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.nav-item.active .nav-sub-item {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to either grab the element, and if that returned null, grab the sibling. This way, it's always possible to select the `.menu-item-dropdown` element. When clicking on the element, it can either be a child or sibling.

**Part of Solution**

```js
var element =
        event.target.querySelector(".menu-item-dropdown") ||
        event.target.nextElementSibling;

element.classList.toggle("hide_drop");
```